# Unable to save multiple images in wordpress

Tags: metabox, gallery

I'm creating meta box to attach gallery of images into posts. But I get only one image after saved. Please correct my callback function below:

```
function save_custom_meta_data($id) {

    /* --- security verification --- */
    if(!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['wp_custom_attachment_nonce'], plugin_basename(__FILE__))) {
      return $id;
    } // end if

    if(defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
      return $id;
    } // end if

    if('page' == $_POST['post_type']) {
      if(!current_user_can('edit_page', $id)) {
        return $id;
      } // end if
    } else {
        if(!current_user_can('edit_page', $id)) {
            return $id;
        } // end if
    } // end if
    /* - end security verification - */

    // Make sure the file array isn't empty
    foreach ($_FILES['wp_custom_attachment']["tmp_name"] as $key => $value) {

        if(!empty($_FILES['wp_custom_attachment']['name'][$key])) {

            // Setup the array of supported file types. In this case, it's just PDF.
            $supported_types = array('application/pdf', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/jpg', 'image/gif');

            // Get the file type of the upload
            $arr_file_type = wp_check_filetype(basename($_FILES['wp_custom_attachment']['name'][$key]));
            $uploaded_type = $arr_file_type['type'];

            // Check if the type is supported. If not, throw an error.
            if(in_array($uploaded_type, $supported_types)) {

                // Use the WordPress API to upload the file
                $upload = wp_upload_bits($_FILES['wp_custom_attachment']['name'][$key], null, file_get_contents($_FILES['wp_custom_attachment']['tmp_name'][$key]));

                if(isset($upload['error']) && $upload['error'] != 0) {
                    wp_die('There was an error uploading your file. The error is: ' . $upload['error']);
                } else {
```

> $upload gives the correct array values of multiple images
>   selected.But  I'm unsure if add_post_meta and update_post_meta are
>   saving the multiple images.

```
                    add_post_meta($id, 'wp_custom_attachment', $upload);

                    update_post_meta($id, 'wp_custom_attachment', $upload);     
                } // end if/else

            } else {

                wp_die("The file type that you've uploaded is not of supported type.");
            } // end if/else

        } // end if
    }


} // end save_custom_meta_data
add_action('save_post', 'save_custom_meta_data');
```

I'm fetching the images like this:

```
$file = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'wp_custom_attachment', false);
```

`var_dump($file)`;//gives me array of same image which is wrong.

I'm not sure how to check if all images are saved? Are they being overwritten and that's why I'm seeing the last images selected when fetching the images using `get_post_meta`?

Answer (score 0):

You are updating the same `post_meta` on each loop. Therefore you are probably saving the last uploaded image only. Try something like this (simplified):

```
foreach ($_FILES['wp_custom_attachment']["tmp_name"] as $key => $value) {
  $post_meta = get_post_meta($id, 'wp_custom_attachment', $upload);

  if( $post_meta ) {
    $post_meta .= ', ' . $upload;
    update_post_meta($id, 'wp_custom_attachment', $post_meta);
  }

  else {
    add_post_meta($id, 'wp_custom_attachment', $upload);
  }
}
```

First I check if the `post_meta` exists. If not, I create it with the value of $upload. If it does exist, I add the new `$upload` to the existing value in `$post_meta`. When you will need to get all the values, you can use `explode()`.

```
$images = explode( ',', $post_meta );
  foreach( $images as $img ) {
    // bla...
  }
```

Another way you can do it is by creating different unique keys for each upload and looping all over them.

```
foreach ($_FILES['wp_custom_attachment']["tmp_name"] as $key => $value) {
  $post_meta = get_post_meta($id, 'wp_custom_attachment_1', $upload);

  if( !$post_meta ) {
    add_post_meta($id, 'wp_custom_attachment_1', $upload);
  }

  else {
    $counter = 1;

    while( $flag !== true ) {
      $post_meta = get_post_meta($id, 'wp_custom_attachment_' . $counter, $upload);

      if( $post_meta ) {
        continue;
      }

      else {
        add_post_meta($id, 'wp_custom_attachment_' . $counter, $upload);
      }

      $counter++;
    }
  }
}
```

The code is raw and simplified.